# ExtJS6 Launch Modal Window fron ViewController

Tags: extjs, modal-dialog

I am attempting to launch a modal window from within a viewcontroller.  Consider the following  code (also located at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1335):

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {
        Ext.define('Window1',{
            extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
            controller: 'winctrl',
            xtype: 'window1',
            initComponent: function(){
                Ext.apply(this,{
                    title:'Window 1',
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400,
                    layout: {type:'hbox',pack:'center',align:'middle'},
                    items:[{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Click Me!',
                        handler: 'btnClickMeClick'
                    }]
                });
                this.callParent(arguments);
            }
        });
        Ext.define('Window2',{
            extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
            xtype: 'window2',
            initComponent: function(){
                Ext.apply(this,{
                    title: 'Window 2',
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    modal: true,
                    //renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    layout: {type:'hbox',pack:'center',align:'middle'},
                    items:[{
                        html: 'Modal Looks Odd',
                        listeners:{
                            afterrender: 'htmlRender'   
                        }
                    }]
                });
                this.callParent(arguments);
            }
        });
        Ext.define('WinCtrl',{
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias:'controller.winctrl',
            btnClickMeClick: function(){
                this.dialog = this.getView().add({xtype:'window2'});
                this.dialog.show();
            },
            htmlRender: function(){
                console.log(this.dialog);
            }
        });
        Ext.widget('window1').show();
    }
});
```

The problem I am running into is that when window 2 is launched it is modal only to the view that launched it and I need the window to be modal to the entire document. If run as is, the htmlRender function will log the window 2 object correctly. I attempted to set the `renderTo: Ext.getBody()` on window 2; however, I am unable to access it's object when it is rendered.  In this case, htmlRender logs an "undefined" for the window 2 object.

I need some help allowing window 2 to be rendered as a modal to the document while allowing me to reference its object.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by setting the `renderConfig:Ext.getBody()` on window, removing the listener on the html item and adding a listener for the show event on window2: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/133j

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the window to that view, replace:

```
this.dialog = this.getView().add({xtype:'window2'})
```

With:

```
this.dialog = Ext.widget('window2');
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1338

Comment: I tried that as well.  Problem is, it takes the scope out of the viewcontroller.  If you put the html config back on the window and listen to "afterrender" it will not find the htmlRender method in the viewcontroller.

Comment: I was able to work around this issue by setting the renderConfig:Ext.getBody() on window, removing the listener on the html item and adding a listener for the show even on the window: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/133j